# Solve the following differential equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

> Solve the following PDE $$\frac{\partial^{2}z}{\partial x^{2}}+z=0,$$ given that when $x=0$, $z=e^{y}$ and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=1$.

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = 1$ for $x = 0$ or $\forall x$?

Comment: @user88595 1 : I have put the question from a book. I did not find the solution convincing.

Comment: My guess would be only for $x=0$ otherwise I don't think it's possible.

Comment: In which case use the normal way to solve a second order linear ODE as so $z(x) = A_1e^{\lambda_1 x} + A_2 e^{\lambda_2 x}$ where $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are the roots of $\lambda^2 + 1 = 0$ and then plug in the initial conditions.

Comment: Or use cos ans sin if you want to avoid complex numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In essential the equation is an ode: the general solution of $z_{xx}+z=0$ is $z=C_1\cos x+C_2\sin x$ where the coefficients are functions of $y$. Substituting the initial condition yields $C_1=e^y$ and $C_2=1$. So the solution is $z(x,y)=e^y\cos x+\sin x$.